# Linux Script: if [ "$hostname" != "(none)" ] comparison doesn't work

Tags: linux, shell

I'm getting hostname and ip address from server(ubuntu 12.04) as explained [here](http://nxhelp.com/blog/2013/1/24/automatically-set-hostname-from-dhcp-in-debian-using-isc-dhcp-client). It works correctly. After a while, i realize that server returns "(none)" as hostname when it is offline. Now i'm trying to eliminate this error by comparing hostname with "(none)". I tried all of these(*) but none of them works:

```
-- Getting hostname here    
hostname=$(grep "host-name" /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.${interface}.leases | tail -n1 | cut -d"\"" -f2 | cut -d"." -f1)

-- Trying to compare it with "(none)"
    * if [ "$hostname" != "(none)" ] then ... else ... fi
    * if [[ $hostname != "(none)" ]] then ... else ... fi
    * nouser="(none)"  if [ "$hostname" != "$nouser" ] then ... else ... fi
```

What am i doing wrong ? Thx for any help.

Comment: `if [ "$hostname" != "(none)" ]; then ... else ... fi` Note the `;` sign after `]`

Comment: I tried it too. It didn't works. And there is also if [ ] statement without ending ";" in code and it works without a problem.

Comment: What's the result you're seeing?

Comment: Replace `grep | tail | cut` with `awk -F'"' '/host-name/ { print $2; exit }' /var/lib/...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semicolon after `]`

```
if [ ... ]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

or newlines:

```
if [ ... ]
then
   ...
else
   ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work;

```
hostname="(foo)"
if [ "$hostname" == "(foo)" ]; then echo "equals"; else echo "not equals"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$HOSTNAME` - my reasoning, which can user to validate other `$` variables:

> wilf@comp:~$ echo $hostname
>   
>   wilf@comp:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
>   comp
>   wilf@comp:~$

For some reason, `$hostname` does not seem to work (Ubuntu 13.10, haven't tried this on other Linuxes)

Comment: You are correct about the environment variables, but OP is *building* a local variable in the script. `For some reason` - *nix is case sensitive, so `$hostname` and `$HOSTNAME` are different variables.

Comment: @admdrew - I guess it's sanity. otherwise `$iii` and `$III` would be the same variable... unless the Turkish locales are set when i and I would be different letters.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Not sure what you mean!

Comment: Also, `HOSTNAME` is set at the start of your shell session (if it is set at all), and most likely never updated until you exit that shell and start a new one. Given that the OP is searching DHCP lease files, I think the object is to pick up when the host name changes due to a new lease, which an environment variable won't do unless you go to the effort to update it after every command or something...

Comment: @admdrew - "For some reason - *nix is case sensitive" - question if `i` and `I` are the same letter depend on your locale. For many locales it's the same letter but in case of tr_TR (AFAIK) they are different. So having case sensitive variables and names in i10n environment is complicated.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Oh, ok, interesting, I did not know that, thank you!